# How to add city markers to a map of Germany?

Tags: curated-data, entity, geographics

I'm trying to draw markers for a list of Germany ZIP codes onto a map. Following the official documentation, it seems as if using [`GeoMarker`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoMarker.html)on values like

```
Entity["City", {"Nürnberg", "Germany"}]
```

should work. But *Mathematica* does not find any location information for German cities:

```
GeoGraphics[
  {GeoMarker[{Entity["City", {"Nürnberg", "Germany"}]}]}
]
```

> Unable to obtain location information for Entity[City,{Nürnberg,Germany}].

I tried several combinations with city names and ZIP codes, but to no avail.
But when I search for Nürnberg on Wolframalpha, they clearly have data on the city!

How can I draw markers from ZIP codes in German cities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function `Interpreter` can find the positions:

```
Interpreter["Location"]["Nürnberg, Germany"]
Interpreter["Location"]["90402, Germany"]
```

Both versions return a `GeoPosition` value.

Starting from a list of ZIP codes, the following works:

```
plzs := {19258, 57399, 90402}
plzsGermany := Map[ToString[#] <> ", Germany" &, plzs]
positions := Map[Interpreter["Location"][#] &, plzsGermany]
GeoGraphics[
  {
    GeoStyling["OutlineMap"], 
    Polygon[Entity["Country", "Germany"]], 
    GeoMarker[positions]
  }, 
  GeoBackground -> Transparent
]
```

[image]

The approach works with city names as well, and should generalize to other countries.

*Warning:* Applied to long lists of zip codes, this can run a while.

Comment: Beware! `Interpreter["Location"]` does return `GeoPosition` from some UK Postcodes, (`Interpreter["Location"] ["NW6 1PG"]` returns `GeoPosition[{51.5472, -0.191049}]`) but sometimes fails ( `Interpreter["Location"] ["NW6 1EH"]` returns failure message *"No geographic location interpretation found. Try again"*). This was reported in CASE:3913717, the response was that **developers "haven't optimized interpreter to handle these inputs. Further conversion of these postal codes to `GeoPositions` would require a custom interpreter"**. It may fail for Germany too.

Comment: @rhermans Yes, some ZIPs failed. Out of the three error messages I got, one was a PO box and two were not even known to Deutsche Post, so I blame my data set. That said, I *did* add `germanPositions := Select[positions, GeoWithinQ[Entity["Country", "Germany"], #] &]` to avoid bad/undesired positions.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks for the warning, anyway! While an approximation of the full data set is fine for my purposes, others may require more precision.

Comment: At least in the UK, the postal codes that did return `GeoPositions` were not necessarily accurate. I find it particularly worrisome that this creates the illusion that works, but in reality, translating postal code to `GeoPositions` is not officially supported, and performance is random.

Comment: For my data, [the result](http://imgur.com/a/Ke9iV) doesn't seem to be all that bad.

Comment: The inaccuracies of GeoPositions I noticed in  London UK, was on the order of hundred of meters, not relevant to countrywide scale.

Answer (score 7):

Entities are not meant to be typed directly.  There is no way to guess the correct format.  Instead, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd>, type the name of the city in any form you like: Nürnberg or Nuremberg will both work, then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.  You'll see this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the interpretation is not correct, you can choose another one through the `...` menu. If everything if fine, you can confirm with the ✓ button (though this is not compulsory).  Now you are ready to use the entity.

If you look at its full form, you will see that it is

```
Entity["City", {"Nuremberg", "Bavaria", "Germany"}]
```

The way you entered it was not correct.

The correct form works fine in `GeoMarker`.

```
GeoGraphics[
 GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"Nuremberg", "Bavaria", "Germany"}]]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this is (in this form) useless when reading about 400 ZIP codes from a CSV. :/ I guess I could, somehow, determine the Bundesland (it's not in the data set; it's irrelevant in Germany for most purposes), but meh.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, Interpreter is good for that. I showed why your Entity didn't work.

Comment: Whoever downvoted: A downvote won't improve the answer but commenting about what's wrong might.

Answer (score 7):

### Using an external API

```
ClearAll[GermanZip2GeoPosition];
GermanZip2GeoPosition[zip_String] := Block[
   {response = Quiet@Import[URLBuild[{"https://api.zippopotam.us", "DE", zip}], "RawJSON"]},
   If[response =!= $Failed,
    Query["places", 1, 
      GeoPosition[ToExpression@{#["latitude"], #["longitude"]}] &][response]
    , Null
    ]
   ];
GermanZip2GeoPosition[zip_Integer] := GermanZip2GeoPosition[ToString[zip]];
SetAttributes[GermanZip2GeoPosition, Listable]
```

### Example

```
GeoGraphics@GeoMarker@GermanZip2GeoPosition@{90402, 90491, 90513, 90518, 90522, 90547, 90552, 90579, 90762, 90768
}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

<sub>Code and plots done in *Mathemathica 11.1.1* on Win7</sub>

Comment: I like seeing API-based solutions a lot... :D

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, however the choice of service is probably less than ideal for Germany. As far as I can tell from comparing [the images I get](http://imgur.com/a/Ke9iV), the two versions mostly agree (some markers move a little this way or that) but zippopotam.us does not know a fair number of ZIP codes.

Comment: @Raphael, if you can find a service that knows German ZIP codes **and** has an API, we should be able to figure out how to interface *Mathematica* with it.

Comment: @J.M. Sure, and this answer explains how. I upvoted it, but I felt I needed to leave a "beware caveat" comment for later visitors.

Comment: FWIW, there seem to be [multiple offerings](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=deutsche%20postleitzahlen%20api) of both free data sets and APIs.

Comment: @Raphael We know Google, still, choosing which of all available hits is worthy of consideration for an answer or a new question is a task you can't expect us to do here.

Comment: @Raphael I second the comments by JM, if you provide the API, we can do the Mathematica coding. Choosing is also a task, and not a particularly easy.

Comment: @rhermans Oh, I'm sorry I wasn't clear: I didn't expect anybody to program the perfect solution for me. I expect to be able to use any API following your example; and if not, I'd open a new question. I consider this question dealt with; I'll wait another day or two and then accept an answer. Thanks for your help!